# Configuring module chan_mobile using Asterisk 13 and FreePBX 12

Tags: mobile, asterisk, gateway, freepbx

I have just installed Asterisk 13 + FreePBX 12.0.71. I installed, also, module chan_mobile and Bluetooth drivers on my Ubuntu 14.04.2LTS Server. I've connected my Nokia C7-00 to my machine, but I have errors when loading module chan_mobile:

```
server*CLI> module load chan_mobile.so
```

> [2015-07-12 15:26:54] ERROR[14478]: chan_mobile.c:4725 load_module: Errors reading config file chan_mobile.conf. Not loading module.

I tried to restart amportal and check if module is loaded

```
amportal restart
asterisk -rx "module show" | grep chan_mobile
```

And the result is:

> chan_mobile.so                 Bluetooth Mobile Device Channel Driver   0          Not Running      extended

Also, I see that file chan_mobile.conf doesn't exist.

Can someone guide me? What should I do?

Comment: Hi there. Just so you know, the community has discussed the practice of adding extra "tags" to question titles (using brackets and bars as separators) and has decided that questions are better without these. Obviously, do use the tag system, but otherwise if you can just write titles in natural flowing English, that is preferred. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found how to find port... For others: Type in asterisk CLI:

```
mobile search
```

And if your mobile is connected you will get some info about that, also the port. For me was port 2.

Comment: Thanks for providing the answer in response to my suggestion. I've moved what I believe is the "answer part" from your question edit to this answer post - we much prefer questions and answers to be separate here, so the API provides the correct data for external users. If I've not selected the right bit, feel free to edit further. Thanks!